# Binary string function with unique one-counting prefixes

Tags: recurrence-relations, binary

I'm looking for a partial function $f$ from binary strings to natural numbers such that the following holds ($x$ and $y$ always represent binary strings, $\epsilon$ is the empty string, $H(x)$ is the Hamming weight of $x$, i.e. the number of $1$s):
$$f(\epsilon)=1$$
$$f(x)>0 \implies f(x+1)=f(x)-1$$
$$x \in Dom(f) = (\nexists y,z :x=y+z,f(y)=0,z \neq \epsilon)$$
$$x\neq y,f(x)=f(y)\implies H(x) \neq H(y)$$
$$\forall n, \exists x: H(x)=n,f(x)=0$$

This function represents a command in a programming language that normally takes a single digit (all represented by $1$ in this function), but $0$ is an extending digit that lets the command take more digits instead. Just letting each $0$ increase the number of desired digits leads to multiple ways to represent the same string of digits, though, like $0011$ and $0101$, which both have $2$ actual accepted digits, when I'd like one of them to accept a different number of digits.

Description of rules:

1. The function is 1 at the empty string (default to accepting a single digit).
2. Appending a 1 to a string decreases the function by 1 if not already 0 (represents accepting a single digit)
3. Any string with a prefix that produces the value 0 shouldn't be in the domain of the function $f$ (this represents a string reaching the correct number of 1s, so it stops accepting more digits), but all other strings should.
4. No two different strings should have the same number of ones and the same value of the function, since then we can add $1$s to the end until both reach zero, and we reach the aforementioned redundant case of two strings accepting the same number of digits.
5. We need to be able to end up with any number we'd like of accepted digits.

Optional: It shouldn't take *more* zeros to accept *fewer* ones (i.e. no $f(0)=3, f(00)=2$)

I'm just having trouble coming up with a solution that would provably work, since I can't just blindly iterate through all strings with the same number of ones and assign values, since previous values can invalidate future strings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following function $f$ satisfies the five conditions:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1& \text{ if $x = \varepsilon$}\\
0& \text{ if $x = 0^k1^{k+1}$ for some $k \geq 0$}\\
\text{undefined}&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Sorry, the third condition was meant to go both ways, I've fixed it.